# How to avoid casting with generic return values?

Tags: java, generics

For the method `getFirstFromEnum` below it is always true that the returned `enum` type is the class that was passed as an argument. Considering that, is there anyway I could alter the method to avoid casting every time I call it?

```
private <E extends Enum<?>> Enum<?> getFirstFromEnum(Class<E> enumClass) {
    return enumClass.getEnumConstants()[0];
}

EnumA foo = (EnumA) getFirstFromEnum(EnumA.class); //can I change method to avoid casting?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you return  `Enum<?>`.
What you want to return is the `Enum` value of the passed enum as argument.
So, specify `E` as return value as it represents the specific `Enum` type you passed.

You could so write :

```
private <E extends Enum<?>> E getFirstFromEnum(Class<E> enumClass) {
  return enumClass.getEnumConstants()[0];
}
```

Comment: Could you try to explain to me the necessity of replacing `<E extends Enum<?>>` with `<E extends Enum<E>>`. They both seem to work

Comment: Hmmm.. Honestly, I don't know. I have the habit to type as much strongly as I can. But you are right : here it is not required. It looks like syntactic sugar. I updated to keep this part as it was.

Comment: @user2651804: this boils down to the question why `java.lang.Enum` has been defined as `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` instead of `Enum<E extends Enum<?>>` or just `Enum<E>`. At the first glance, there seem to be some importance behind it, but actually, it would perfectly work without. As demonstrated by `java.lang.Comparable` which has been defined as `Comparable<T>` instead of `Comparable<T extends Comparable<T>>`…

Comment: @Holger `Comparable<T>` doesn't work properly. Writing `class Foo implements Comparable<Object>` ought to be a compile error. It's a complete nonsense for the `T` not to extend `Comparable` because the interface specifies that `a.compareTo(b)` should always have the opposite signum to `b.compareTo(a)`.

Comment: @Paul Boddington: A declaration like `interface Comparable<T extends Comparable<T>>` still doesn't prevent you from writing nonsense like `class Foo implements Comparable<String>`. In contrast, you can't declare `enum` types with nonsensical generic signatures, as these are generated by the compiler, regardless of how the type parameter of `class Enum` has been declared.

Comment: @Holger Yes, the enum example is a special case because of what you say. You don't get anything at all from that weird declaration, except that it's a good hint that you're supposed to write `<E extends Enum<E>>` when you write generic methods involving enums. The `Comparable` example is different, and while I agree you can't prevent people writing nonsense, I'm fairly sure the declaration would be `Comparable<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` if it were introduced now (rather than generifying an existing interface).